# Retrieve only the keys & values which I stored in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I have created UserDefaults with suite,

```
self.moviesWatchedUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.tv.2020")
```

And storing the info in the plist like

```
self.moviesWatchedUserDefaults.set(data, forKey: key).
```

Now, while retrieving, I wanted to retrieve all keys & values. For which I am using,

```
var watchedList = self.moviesWatchedUserDefaults?.dictionaryRepresentation()
```

But the list which is returned not only contains the items which I stored, but also other keys like `NSLanguages`, `AppleKeyboards`, `AppleKeyboardsExpanded`, `CarCapabilities`, etc.,

How to retrieve all the keys&values (only the ones which I stored) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full list of known keys, you can filter the dictionary.

In the following example I have all my known keys in an enum and I can filter the dictionary, keeping only my keys:

```swift
enum UserDefaultsKey: String, CaseIterable {
    case foo
    case bar
    case baz
}

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(42, forKey: UserDefaultsKey.foo.rawValue)

let onlyMyValues = userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation().filter { (key, _) -> Bool in
    UserDefaultsKey.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }.contains(key)
}

print(onlyMyValues) // prints ["foo": 42]
```

Comment: No, these are like Unknown keys that are received from the backend.

Comment: In this case I'd suggest two options:
1. Track the keys you use to save into UserDefaults and store them for later retrieving.
2. Adopt a more suitable storage, like a custom plist file or a database. CoreData might be a good choice.